# Methionine/Cysteine under redox control

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, biochemistry

Methionine and cysteine are the principal sulfur-containing amino acids, and 
oxidation of cysteine and methionine residues had been well studied. How come NOT all proteins carry Methionine and/or Cysteine are under Redox Control?